# How can we use gulp to compress files

Tags: laravel

I am using `Laravel 5` and I am trying to compress my `css` and `js` files 
How can I achieve `.min.css` or `min.js` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is passing `--production` while you're applying `gulp` in command line